# Convert com.google.gson.JsonObject to org.json.simple.JSONObject

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson

Simple but tricky, how could I convert `com.google.gson.JsonObject` to `org.json.simple.JSONObject` without know the inner properties or manually parsing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution so far is use `org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser` to do it:

```
(JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse("{...}"); // JSON string generated via `com.google.gson.Gson`
```

Enjoy!